# Resources to lookup MAUI XAML tags and their properties

Tags: maui

Does anyone have a list of all XAML tags (and the list of properties each has) used in MAUI?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there is a list that is only focussing what is available in XAML. Then again, a lot of the things you can do in code can be done in XAML.

I think a great way to start is to look at the [official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/). Namely the controls, pages and layouts will be something to look at because that is most of the time what you will be putting into XAML files. From there you will automatically branch out into styles, themes and other resources that you can have in XAML as well as you find yourself needing them.

If you really need ALL the public APIs (read: all the classed, methods and objects) then you want to look at the API docs. This is also the documentation that you will find inside of Visual Studio in the IntelliSense. We have published those [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/?view=net-maui-6.0).

While this has a description of all the APIs that are there in .NET MAUI, a lot of them are currently lacking a useful description right now. We are working hard on improving that. For most, hopefully, the code should be self-descriptive enough and at least you can make a connection to what to search for our try out yourself in code.